# How to combine uint8 and uint16 bytes in array with arduino?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I have complex variable byte array that I need send thru serial in arduino, Im using esp32 chip so I think I should have enough RAM to deal with it. But Im not sure how to do it, because some variables are uint8, some uint16 and I must send them in 1 piece thru Serial.write(). While all variable are uint8 I have no problems eg:

```
    void loop() {
    uint8_t oil_temp = 0xFF; //lets assume its variable, not constant
    uint8_t ambient_temp = 0xFF; 
    uint8_t coolant_temp = 0xFF;
    uint8_t interior_temp = 0xFF;
    uint8_t main_array[4] = {oil_temp, ambient_temp, coolant_temp, interior_temp};
    Serial.write(main_array, 4); // sends FF FF FF FF
  delay(1000);
}
```

Problem comes when I add uint16 variables

```
    void loop() {
    uint8_t oil_temp = 0xFF; //lets assume its variable, not constant
    uint8_t ambient_temp = 0xFF;
    uint8_t coolant_temp = 0xFF;
    uint8_t interior_temp = 0xFF;
    uint16_t engine_speed = 0xAAEE;
    uint8_t main_array[6] = {oil_temp, ambient_temp, coolant_temp, interior_temp, engine_speed};
    Serial.write(main_array, 6); // sends FF FF FF FF EE 00
  delay(1000);
}
```

If I try `Serial.write(main_array, 5);` it sends "FF FF FF FF EE"

I expect to get "FF FF FF FF AA EE" so I could easily parse it on other end. Please help

Comment: You could split the 2 bytes up, but then you need to properly reassemble them on the receiving side: `uint8_t main_array[6] = {oil_temp, ambient_temp, coolant_temp, interior_temp, (engine_speed >> 8) & 0xFF, engine_speed & 0xFF};`

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed

Comment: I would simply issue `serial.write` two times: uit8s first and then uint16s.

Answer (score 2):

I think what is happening is the data from engine_speed is being mangled because its expecting uint8_t values throughout your assignment.

I would build `main_array` more explicitly to avoid issues like this.

```
 uint8_t main_array[6];
 main_array[0] = oil_temp;
 main_array[1] = ambient_temp;
 main_array[2] = coolant_temp;
 main_array[3] = interior_temp;
 main_array[4] = engine_speed >> 8;
 main_array[5] = engine_speed & 0xFF;
```

You can switch the assignments for 'main_array[4]' and 'main_array[5]' depending if you want to work big endian or little endian.

Comment: Can you show me example if engine_speed would be uint32? eg `engine_speed = 0xAABBCCDD;` ? Ive tried `main_array[4] = engine_speed >> 8;
 main_array[5] = engine_speed >> 8;
 main_array[6] = engine_speed >> 8;
 main_array[7] = engine_speed & 0xFF;` but it outputs CC CC CC DD, I didnt understood 0xFF part I think

Comment: @TheAfrizzz `& 0xFF` is done for filter 8 lsb only. `>>` operator is the right shift. In order to get the 16 most significant bits you have to shift more:  `main_array[4] = engine_speed >> 24; main_array[5] = engine_speed >> 16 & 0xFF; main_array[6] = engine_speed >> 8 & 0xFF; main_array[7] = engine_speed & 0xFF;`

Comment: Ps: if the answer was useful for you, upvote it. It's important! That's how good answers (and good contributors) are rewarded!

Comment: As Im new user, it dont allow me to upvote yet. Anyway your answer is perfect, it works like a charm. Today I learned something about bitshift, thanks a lot!